# My boss changed behaviour and I stopped eating with the team. Will this affect my job?

Tags: professionalism

Ours is a big company, but my team is small and consists of 4 members. I joined here 6 months before, and my boss was my lunch mate before he became my manager (since I was in other team). Now he is my manager. The problem is he started ignoring me and taunting/insulting me in front of all, which is hindering my self-confidence.

I have left lunch group and started eating alone. Will this affect my job, since I know he will be blamed indirectly for departure of me from that group?

Comment: You seem to be asking us to read your boss's mind. We have no way to guess what the problem is or how he will react to your deciding you would rather not sit with that group right now. If he is at all rational this should not harm you, but if he was rational you wouldn't be in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

> how to handle it?

Did you try talking to him. If not, then you need to. Ask him for a personal meeting of about 15 minutes, and let him know that his continuous taunting and belittling has been affecting your self-confidence, and as a result, your productivity too.

If he is a rational person, he would understand and try to behave properly.

> but i want know whether this effects my job since i know he will be
>   blamed indirectly for departure of me from that group

If it's affecting your productivity, it is affecting your job and you **need to** speak up. In case, your boss continues to behave then same way even after confrontation, then you need to escalate the matter to higher authorities.

However, **talking always helps.** So, try to get your problem over to him.